# Need help with mybb forum robots.txt file

Tags: subdomain, web-crawlers, robots.txt, forum

I have installed the mybb forum in subdomain of my site. 
The link to my site is [here](http://forum.mytabletguru.com/).

but when I search Google even the pages that are disallowed are also index. What's wrong with the *robots.txt* file?

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /captcha.php
Disallow: /editpost.php
Disallow: /member.php
Disallow: /misc.php
Disallow: /modcp.php
Disallow: /moderation.php
Disallow: /newreply.php
Disallow: /newthread.php
Disallow: /online.php
Disallow: /printthread.php
Disallow: /private.php
Disallow: /ratethread.php
Disallow: /report.php
Disallow: /reputation.php
Disallow: /search.php
Disallow: /sendthread.php
Disallow: /task.php
Disallow: /usercp.php
Disallow: /usercp2.php
Disallow: /calendar.php
Disallow: /*action=emailuser*
Disallow: /*action=nextnewest*
Disallow: /*action=nextoldest*
Disallow: /*year=*
Disallow: /*action=weekview*
Disallow: /*action=nextnewest*
Disallow: /*action=nextoldest*
Disallow: /*sort=*
Disallow: /*order=*
Disallow: /*mode=*
Disallow: /*datecut=*
```

Comment: When did this file go live? Google might have indexed those pages before you made that robots.txt, and then it might take a while for them to disappear.

Comment: I have added the robot file more then a month ago.

Comment: Are you using seo friendly urls? if so using .php in the robots is irrelevant. Additionally, as Ivo said it can take months to remove urls if these were already indexed, if concerned about these URLS then login to webmaster tools and speed up the process by removing them using the url removal tool. Additionally using 'noindex' actually within the meta along with robots is considered better and more reliable.

Comment: It may be helpful if you post the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to diagnose problems with your *robots.txt* file is to use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).  They have a tool there that is specifically meant to figure out this kind of issue.   Once you are in GWT, navigate to:

Crawl → Blocked URLs

Once there, it will import your *robots.txt* file in the upper box.  You can test changes by editing there (but it won't save them back to your site, of course.)  The lower box is for a list of URLs that you want to test.  Choose some URLs that you want to block but which are indexed and test them.

---

It is possible that nothing is wrong with your *robots.txt* file.

If you recently added rules to your *robots.txt* file it may take a month or more until the pages get removed from Google's index.  Google doesn't instantly de-index pages once you block those pages.  Google won't de-index pages until next time it tries to crawl them.  If you would like them removed sooner, you can request pages be removed from the index.  In GWT, navigate to:

Google Index → Remove URLs

According to their [removal requirements](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/59819?hl=en) the pages must be blocked (for example by *robots.txt*) before they can be removed.

---

*robots.txt* may not prevent Google from including a page in the index altogether.  In some cases, when a page has enough external links, Google may include the page in the index and use the anchor text of the inbound links to know what it is about.   In such cases, you can request that the page not be indexed by allowing Googlebot to crawl the page but putting a [meta robots noindex tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) into the head.